# Designing Firestore database for app with many users per account

Tags: database-design, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, nosql, ngrx

I am a UI developer with almost no database/backend experience. I am creating an app for scheduling appointments with Angular, NgRx, Firestore, and Firebase Auth. I've done some research and have a general feel for how to design a NoSQL database, but I get the feeling that I'm going about things in a weird way.

So far, I have a working frontend and have setup Firebase Authentication, so I can successfully register and login. My issue is figuring out a good way to know which account each user is associated with, as there can potentially be many users per account. For more context, each account is a company and each user is either an admin, client, or employee.

My current solution, that is working but seems hacky, is to do the following:

1. When an admin registers, I create a new account in my `accounts` collection as well as a new user in my `users` collection, which is a sibling to `accounts`. I generate an `id` for the new account object and use the same one for an `accountId` in the new user object. Each user also contains an `id`, which matches the `uid` generated via Firebase Authentication.
2. When a user logs in, I grab their `uid` that is returned from Firebase Auth and use that to find the `user` object with a matching `id` from the `users` collection I created. From that object, I grab the `accountId` stored in there and use that for all of my API calls so I can get account specific data.

Here's a simplified example of what my data looks like:

```
accounts: [
  { id: 'abc123', appointments: [...], clients: [...], employees: [], ... },
  { id: 'def456', appointments: [...], clients: [...], employees: [], ... },
  ...
];

// id matches uid from Firebase Auth.
// accountId is used to find which account to get data from
users: [
  { id: 'wmYUjdnJKks', accountId: 'abc123' },
  { id: 'yuRVjGnBLkm', accountId: 'def456' },
  ...
];
```

So if I want to get a list of all the appointments for a specific account, I will do something like this:

```
this.afs
  .collection('accounts')
  .doc(accountId)
  .collection<Appointment>('appointments')
  .get()
```

I have not yet worked out how I will handle clients and employees registering and knowing how to associate them with the correct account.

Hopefully this isn't the wrong type of question to ask on here, but I don't want to take a bad approach to setting all this up only to have to do major refactoring later. If there are any recommendations on how to set up Firestore for an app like this, both for admins and for clients/employees, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, I would consider renaming *accounts* to *companies* or *organizations* to disambiguate user and organization documents.

```
companies: [
  { id: 'abc123', appointments: [...], clients: [...], employees: [], ... },
  { id: 'def456', appointments: [...], clients: [...], employees: [], ... },
  ...
];

users: [
  { id: 'wmYUjdnJKks', accountId: 'abc123' },
  { id: 'yuRVjGnBLkm', accountId: 'def456' },
  ...
];
```

I think you chose the better of two approaches that come to mind when trying to fetch communal documents. The approach you went with is being able to query appointments by accountId.

To get more granular with an approach that may allow you to more easily adapt to user-specific/permissions-based access, since you said *admins*, is to store a list of users who are authorized to access a given document. This might look something like this:

```
appointments: [
  { id: 'randomlyGenerated1', accountId: 'abc123', users: ['wmYUjdnJKks', 'user2'] },
  { id: 'randomlyGenerated2', accountId: 'def456', users: ['yuRVjGnBLkm', 'user4' },
  ...
];
```

Where this might come into play would be if an admin can see an appointment a user shouldn't, you can either query by accountId or query where the `array contains` the user's ID. This will involve keeping the lists of users updated.

Alternatively, you can just give each person a role and query for that. Nicely, you can use numbers to define the roles, e.g. 10 = admin, and query for role > 6. That way you can easy set the permissions thresholds, but of course you'd be trading off user-specific permissions.